# If I'm using PostgreSQL, do I need a server too? Like AWS RDS?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my CS program, I was told I should learn SQL for my databases.

If I'm using PostgreSQL, do I also need a SQL server to go along with it? Is PostgreSQL a language, a server, or both? Is there even a SQL language or is it only servers?

Background: I downloaded Postgres because hey, that has SQL in the name, it works and I'm under the impression it's a pretty good choice anyway. But I couldn't figure out through their website if it needs a companion server, so I went looking for one and found AWS RDS.

The impression I have is that Postgres is the language and AWS RDS is the server, and they serve different functions. But I'm not sure about any of that.

Comment: Postgres is an alternative to the other databases like Sql Server, Oracle, MySQL etc. AWS RDS is a wrapper around whatever database server you choose, It offers scaling, backups, standby capability (ie switch from primary to secondary server) etc. Postgres can also run standalone as a server, but then you have to manage all that yourself. It does not need a companion server, it acts as a database server in its own right.

Comment: @JohnD Gotcha, that helps a ton. I was getting a bit overwhelmed by the volume of information out there for people wayyyy more advanced than me. So is Postgres all by itself appropriate for a simple website?

Comment: Postgres has its own SQL language called pgsql. Sql Server has a SQL language called T-sql etc. They all more or less stick to the official SQL standard which only covers query, insert, update and delete syntax. These languages add procedural logic like IF, ELSE etc.

Comment: @JohnD Ohh okay. So effectively Postgres is both the language and the server?

Comment: Yes, it certainly can handle a simple web application.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - Postgres is a package of software which you install to create a database server and the pgsql language is part of that.

Comment: @John: There is no such thing as a "pgsql language". [SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql.html) is the name of the main declarative language. There is also the [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) server-side procedural language (among many others).

Comment: The irony is that "Postgres" does *not* actually have "SQL" in its name; it's formal alias, PostgreSQL, *does*, however.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Postgres and it is an excellent product (and free).
I would install it standalone first. It does come with its own client tools, which you use to communicate with the database server, which runs independently as a service. However, you might be better off installing something like SqlWorkbench as a client tool (which I use). In the config you specify the machine Postgres is running on (which can be your local computer for testing purposes) and the port to connect on. Essentially, the client sends your instructions to Postgres server and the server returns the resultsets associated with your instructions. The client also formats the resultsets into a nice readable "spreadsheet" format with rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you're learning too many new topics at the same time.
Ok. I'll try to answer.

SQL stands for 'Structured Query Language', and serves as a 'standard' for many vendors that in much ways respects its fundamentals. Oracle, MySQL (now owned by Oracle), MariaDB and PostreSQL are some vendors.

Main thing with SQL code I would recommend you to identify every time you look at it, is to understand if it belongs to DML or DDL. DML stands for 'Data Manipulation Language' and refers to SQL instructions which 'modifies' data.  DDL stands for 'Data Declaration Language' which defines or 'alter' de structure on which data will be stored.

Another important concept is atomicity of data manipulation. You can confirm a change or roll it back before it is persisted. This thing corresponds to 'commit' changes or do a 'rollback'. It's some kind of advanced concept, but generally happens "automatically" with standard client configurations. Later, you would have to know about it while programming some system module which interacts with databases.

When you think of the SQL 'server', it refers to the software configured/installed which has the responsability of manage persistence of data within some kind of 'instance' of persistence, allocated in some system with data storage capabilities. AWS implements this service in the cloud, and RDS is the product which supports many kind of SQL flavors to choose (Oracle, Postgresql, etc.)

If you are comfortable with Docker, I recomend you learn the basics which would help you setup and destroy databases many times, which is useful to develop and test locally. Next command, let you start a Postgresql database configured with open port 5432. You can see the server log through docker and use some SQL client to get connected. When you press Ctrl+C everything will be deleted. Of course there are other ways to keep data persistent, but this command would be an easy starting point.

`$ docker run --rm -p 5432:5432 --name some-postgres-container-name -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres:13.3`

*Side note: it's better to get used to work with specific docker image versions always (not 'latest').*

More details of it usage here: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

> if I'm using PostgreSQL, do I also need a SQL server to go along with
> it? Is PostgreSQL a language, a server, or both? Is there even a SQL
> language or is it only servers lol? I'm genuinely trying to figure
> this out myself, but basically everything I read is beyond my scope of
> competence and confuses me more. I'm learning the syntax of SQL well
> enough, but I'm so confused about everything on the most fundamental
> level.

By the way "SQL Server" is Microsoft's SQL flavor, just another one. Don't be confused with the concept of having some SQL server configured.

Yes, you can think of PostgreSQL as a language too, which shares most of its syntax and semantics with other SQL vendors. Yes, there is a 'basic' SQL language shared and compatible between all vendors; some share more aspects than others. In terms of Venn diagrams, you can think of many circles representing each one, Microsoft's SQL Server, Oracle SQL, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. sharing the very most of its elements, where each element is a SQL instruction.

When dealing with Databases in general, keep in mind that they helps to modelate situations of 'real world' scenarios or software systems. SQL allows to 'talk' to implementation of "Relational Databases" wich is one kind of database modeling, but there are others too. ER Diagrams helps to represent the 'structure' of a database in a conceptual manner.  I like DBeaver because it has an integrated ER diagram generator wich helps to understand the structure of a given database instance.

Answer (score 1):

First I'll try to answer the questions you asked. There is a SQL language, but in practice it is not strictly standardized. There are many offerings for databases and database servers. Many of these are discussed below.

Any database you pick will give you the chance to learn basics of SQL queries and this knowledge will serve you well even if you switch to a different database later.

Specifically, when it comes to PostgreSQL, it is a [Relational Database Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system). It is a software that operates as a server. You can install it on your personal computer running Windows, Linux, or MacOS. You can also install in on a dedicated server computer where you'll get better performance and uptime. Further, there are many companies that offer PostgreSQL hosting including Amazon RDS and Google Cloud but they're not free.

For a CS student, PostreSQL installed on your personal computer might be a reasonable choice. But you have lots of options. Read on....

For a CS program, your choice of database will depend on:

- what degree of portability you need
- how much data you have
- how many users will connect to database
- what kinds of jobs you might pursue after graduation

### Portability

If you think you want to ship your database with your application, then your best bet is probably [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html). By some accounts it can handle several million rows worth of data and still be performant. However, it's not great if you need for multiple users to connect to the same database. Your data can get corrupted in many multi-user scenarios.

### How Much Data and Users

For large data and large users, you'll want to consider the client/server heavy hitters:

- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/)
- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/)/[MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/)
- [Oracle](https://oracle.com/database)
- [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/sql-server)

These databases will support large quantities of data any many simultaneous connections. But if you want to distribute the database with your application, it's not a good idea. Or if you want to demonstrate your app, you need to ensure that a connection to a server will be available. All of these databases come with a free version, but the last two will have the most restrictions.

### After Graduation

Now you're looking to the future and possibly what kind of skills you want to put on your resume. If you think you'll end up in a corporate environment that is already well established, they will likely already have a preferred database and it could be any of the ones listed here (SQLite or the "heavy hitters"). If you want to position yourself as developing apps with low overhead cost, you'll gravitate towards SQLite/PostgreSQL/MySQL. If you think you're going to be some kind of database administrator working in a buttoned-up corporate environment, those companies tend to favor SQL Server and Oracle.

Good luck. Any choice you make will probably be fine. Knowing some flavor of SQL is useful for your future endeavors.

Answer (score -1):

SQL is a language like any other language but working on database. It is called SQL because it works on structured data like table (i.e rows and columns). After reading the documentation of PostgreSQL, I think we do not need any separate server installation. You can download it from [here](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads). If you are facing any issues with it I suggest using MySQL workbench. Although installation may take longer time, but its easy to understand.